# Changing the color of the chart label axis

Tags: python, visualization, altair, vega-lite

My visualization:

[image: visualization]

I have made the above visualization with altair and would like to know if it is possible to add other colors to the labels like I did with hook, that matches the color of the legend. I would like to do the same for the other tools/labels on the y-axis but can't find a way to do so (a different color for each label).

Here is the code I used to generate this in case someone is looking for how to color a label.

```
heatmap = alt.Chart(
    new_df
).mark_rect().encode(
    x = alt.X('Time:O',  axis=alt.Axis(labels=False)),
    y = alt.Y('tool:N', axis=alt.Axis(labelColor=alt.condition('datum.value == "hook"', alt.value('red'), alt.value('blue'))))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Just a heads up for future posts that it is a good idea to post your dataset or use one of the sample ones from the Altair gallery. This makes it quicker for others to test your code and post a reply.

Answer (score 1):

VegaLite supports multiple tests in the same condition, but I don't think it is possible to write with `alt.Condition`. However, you can see that `alt.Condition` returns a dictionary so you could write this dictionary directly and pass a list of tests:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd


source = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD'],
    'b': [28, 55, 43, 50]})

# You could use datum.value instead of datum.label
label_colors = {
    'condition': [
        {'test' : 'datum.label == "AAA"', 'value': 'steelblue'},
        {'test' : 'datum.label == "BBB"', 'value': 'purple'}],
     'value': 'red'}  # The default value if no condition is met

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('a', axis=alt.Axis(labelColor=label_colors)),
    y='b')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! that was precisely was I was looking for! Very useful :)